# Can I use alternate branch names with OpenID Connect in GitLab pipeline when authenticating to Azure

Tags: azure, gitlab, gitlab-ci, openid-connect, azure-cli

When using an alternate branch name such as *test-branch* or *username/branch-name* the pipeline fails.

Can I use alternate branch names when authenticating to Azure with OpenID Connect in GitLab?

I am testing a simple GitLab CICD job logging in using an Azure Service Principal with OpenID. The pipeline runs successfully when I execute the pipeline using *main* branch as shown in the GitLab documents:

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/azure/

```
project_path:gitlab-group/gitlab-project:ref_type:branch:ref:main
```

[image]

When I try to execute the same pipeline on a new branch after updating the Federated Credentials *Subject Identifier* in the app registration, the pipeline fails when running from the new branch.

```
project_path:gitlab-group/gitlab-project:ref_type:branch:ref:test-branch
```

[image]

**Pipeline Script**

```
  script:
- az cloud set -n "AzureCloud"
- az login --service-principal -u $CLIENT_ID -t $TENANT_ID --federated-token $CI_JOB_JWT_V2
- terraform init -reconfigure
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial variable configuration was causing the issue because I had the protect flag selected. This was causing me to get a false negative in the output. After echoing out the vars I realized nothing was being output to the shell which caused an empty arg being passed into the az cli login command, thus creating the error. User Error , i.e. the issue was between the chair and keyboard.

Make sure you do not have protect variable checked in GitLab CICD variables if the branch you are working on is not a protected branch.

[image]